# How can I reduce distance between column names and X-axis label in gplots::heatmap.2()

Tags: r, heatmap

I have the following code:

```
  my_palette <- colorRampPalette(rev(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(11, "RdBu")))(n = 50)
  par(mar = c(7, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1)
  gplots::heatmap.2(as.matrix(mtcars),
    Colv = TRUE,
    Rowv = TRUE,
    col = my_palette,
    density.info = "none",
    key = TRUE,
    scale = "none",
    ylab = "Y_LABEL",
    xlab = "X_LABEL",
    trace = "none",
    margins = c(12, 8))
```

It produces this plot:

[image]

As you can see above, the distance between "X_LABEL" and column names
is too far. How can I reduce it?

Comment: I suggest playing around with `margins =`, `lhei =` and `lwid=`

Comment: How about `margins = c(6,8)`